# Scrape nginx logs with fluentd and push the metrics to prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, prometheus, fluentd

I have a nginx k8s deployment. I am running fluentd as a sidecar inside my nginx pod.
The nginx config look like below:

```
data:
  nginx.conf: |
    events {
      worker_connections  1024;
    }
    http {
        log_format prometheus '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" $upstream_response_time';
        server {
            access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log prometheus;
            listen 80;
            server_name localhost;
            location / {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
                index index.html;
            }
        }
    }
```

My fluentd conf looks like below:

```
data:
  fluent.conf: |
    <source>
        @type prometheus_tail_monitor
    </source>
    <source>
        @type tail
        <parse>
        @type regexp
        expression /^(?<timestamp>.+) (?<stream>stdout|stderr)( (.))? (?<remote>[^ ]*) (?<host>[^ ]*) (?<user>[^ ]*) \[(?<time>[^\]]*)\] \"(?<method>\w+)(?:\s+(?<path>[^\"]*?)(?:\s+\S*)?)?\" (?<status_code>[^ ]*) (?<size>[^ ]*)(?:\s"(?<referer>[^\"]*)") "(?<agent>[^\"]*)" (?<urt>[^ ]*)$/
            time_format %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z
            keep_time_key true
            types size:integer,reqtime:float,uct:float,uht:float,urt:float
        </parse>
        tag nginx
        path /var/log/nginx/access.log
        pos_file /tmp/fluent_nginx.pos
    </source>
    <filter nginx>
        @type prometheus
    </filter>
```

I am using `nginx` image for nginx container and `rohithmn01/krishna-fluentd` for fluentd container in my nginx deployemnt.

My nginx pod is running fine with 2 container - nginx and fluentd.
But when i check the fluentd conatiner log, i could see the below error/exception:

```
[warn]: #0 pattern not matched: "10.121.1.4 - - [08/Feb/2023:22:23:30 +0000] \"GET / HTTP/1.1\" 304 0 \"-\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36\" -"
```

Could you please help me here..!

Comment: Why are you not using the [nginx parser plugin](https://docs.fluentd.org/parser/nginx) instead of `regexp`?

Comment: JFYI, nginx can write logs JSON in format, which is generally much easier to parse.

Comment: @Azeem - was not aware of this nginx plugin - thank you for pointing. Will try this and update the results here.